# PosgreSQL14, why showing incorrect timestamptz value?

Tags: postgresql-14

I use PostgreSQL-14, I have a timestamptz field type in a table which has a default value set to timezone('utc'::text, now())

my location is in Indonesia, so it's +07:00

currently is 11:22:52AM and I have just created one record but it displays 2023-12-30 04:22:52.440 +0700, it's incorrect, isn't it?

based on the default value set is UTC, but my opinion it should shows 2023-12-30 04:22:52.440 +0000, if it shows +0700 then it's supposed to show 2023-12-30 11:22:52.440 +0700

I ran "show time zone" and it returns Asia/Jakarta

any body can give me an advice?